# Erroneous conversion to lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, expression, changelistener

I currently work with JavaFx in Netbeans IDE, however Eclipse behaves probably the same. When I use `for-loop` it usually offends me to convert the statement to lambda expression. Sometime I find it useful until it gives the erroneous expression.

I try to apply the conversion tool to the event, when the selected item in a `ComboBox` [is changed](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm#BABDFEFC):

```
command.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override 
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {                
        System.out.println(t1);              
    }    
});
```

The conversion results in:

```
command.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) -> {
    System.out.println(t1);    
});
```

that looks a bit nicer, however is erroneous:

> no suitable method found for addListener((Observabl[...]1); })

When I keep the original code, it works like a charm. Why my IDE offers me a not correct conversion? How to fix the functional method to work well?

Comment: How is `command` declared?

Comment: `however Eclipse behaves probably the same` : it's better not to speculate.  Try Eclipse and see how it works; if you don't want to do that, then remove this phrase.  Without evidence of a problem in Eclipse, this might just be a Netbeans bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

I just tried your example on IntelliJ (sorry, I don't have NetBeans installed) and it generates the proper code and runs fine:

```
new ChoiceBox<String>()
    .valueProperty()
    .addListener((ov, t, t1) -> System.out.println(t1));
```

---

Your original code is incomplete, `ObservableValue` needs a type parameter, i.e.: `ObservableValue<? extends String>`. If you do not provide one, the compiler is unable to infer the correct type

Comment: I have used the code from the Oracle Docs:  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm. Giving me the same result when using `ObservableValue<? extends String>`.

Comment: I edited my answer, I have no compile errors on IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks, it works. however I use the `ComboBox` instead of the `ChoiceBox`.